# Unix shell script error

Tags: linux, unix

If i use

```
ssh -Y username@hostname
```

and reach at another host and type x clock & it is working fine.But if i use it in script In online like

```
ssh -Y username@hostname x clock & ;
```

it gives me error as ksh: x clock: not found.

Please suggest.

Comment: add the path to clock in the script

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that it should be `xclock` and not `x clock` (no space!). If you want to execute commands over SSH then ideally you would have something along the lines:

`ssh user@host 'ls -lrt'`

Answer (score 1):

just run:

```
ssh -Y username@hostname  clock
```

the script you're using tries to exec the command `x` which doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command on a single line, your remote shell will be in non-interactive mode. Because of that different scripts are executed in the remote shell, and because of that, your `PATH` setting is different.

One way to fix this is to find the script that sets the `PATH` of interactive shells, also find the script that is used by non-interactive shells, and adjust the latter to set the `PATH` similarly as the first.

Another solution that might be simpler is to use the full path in your command, follow these steps:

1. Login using `ssh`, as usual, and check the full path of the command you want to run. If the command is `xclock` then you can check its full path with `which xclock`, for example:

   ```
   $ which xclock 
   /usr/X11/bin/xclock
   ```
2. Logout, and run your one-line command, but using the full path like this:

   ```
   ssh -Y username@hostname /usr/X11/bin/xclock
   ```

Comment: Yes Janos, i checked the PATH's are diff but how to set PATH in startup script Please suggest.

Comment: hi Janos,  I tried same and now it is giving me error as     xauth:  not found.
stty: : Not a typewriter
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to 10.100.2.23:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Comment: That is a different question. Ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead and share with me the link and I can try to answer it.